# PropTypes: Impact on bundle size?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Simple question:

Does [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) increase the shipped bundle size and will it display in development mode only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how do you build your project. If you use *webpack* and set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production` than `PropTypes` doesn't include entire type checks to your bundle

You can check [`source code`](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/index.js) in order to understand what will be included in your bundle for each environment.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  var ReactIs = require('react-is');

  // By explicitly using `prop-types` you are opting into new development behavior.
  var throwOnDirectAccess = true;
  module.exports = require('./factoryWithTypeCheckers')(ReactIs.isElement, throwOnDirectAccess);
} else {
  // By explicitly using `prop-types` you are opting into new production behavior.
  module.exports = require('./factoryWithThrowingShims')();
}
```

`factoryWithThrowingShims` just provides shims for all PropTypes methods in order to avoid exceptions in your code when you call some method from PropTypes in the production environment. It means that the entire code from `PropTypes/factoryWithTypeCheckers.js` will be included only when `process.env.NODE_ENV` is not equal to `production`. If you need to completely *(even `Shims`)*, remove `PropTypes` from your code, you need to use some [babel plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types).

Answer (score 1):

You would use the PropTypes in the `devDependencies` of the `package.json`. So no, it does not increase the production build.

Comment: What about components code? Will prop-types stuff be removed on build?

Answer (score 1):

You would use this babel plugin to remove unneccesary propTypes.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types

Comment: Are there situations where you would want to actually include it in production? I am confused as to why this would even be an option? In my limited understanding on the topic, prop-types is supposed to help you in development. 

Are there use cases here that I am missing?

Comment: I don't like propTypes actually, but sometimes, when you log your javascript errors - it can help with wrong parameters of functions.